Flask. При обработке ошибки ZeroDivisionError в cтандарте JSON-RPC, вместо кода ошибки 400 , отображается 500
У меня программа-калькулятор для базовых действий. При делении на ноль выбрасывается исключение, которое я отрабатываю, но в итоге в коде ответа вместо 422 выходит 500. Причина непонятна.
Код:
import operator
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_jsonrpc import JSONRPC

app = Flask(__name__)
jsonrpc = JSONRPC(app, "/api", enable_web_browsable_api=True)


@jsonrpc.method("calc.truediv")
def truediv(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    try:
        result = operator.truediv(a, b)
        return result
    except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
        response = jsonify(
            {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": 4,
                "error": {"code": -32000, "message": str(exc)},
            }
        )
        return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", debug=True)


Должно получиться примерно так:

У меня получает так:


res = response.status_code - вот тут вас ничего не смущает?

@andreymal
Я изменил код, когда выбрасывается исключение, но у меня всё равно выходит ошибка.

@andreymal Нет, я хочу, чтобы в статусе вместо кода ответа 500, был 422. А правее его "на ноль делить нельзя!"

А хотя стоп, вы ж используете другую библиотеку, у которой вообще нет нормальной документации... это печально

В общем я поковырялся в исходниках этой библиотеки и заявляю, что она сломана и непригодна к использованию — её авторы прикрутили mypyc, не позаботившись о корректности типов в своём коде, из-за чего теперь не работает как минимум одна функция (возможно, гораздо больше, но проверять всё я не буду)

@andreymal Раз такие "пироги", то сделал по простому 1)Что функция возвращает или float или str  2)  except ZeroDivisionError:        return "На ноль делить нельзя"   Ну и всё. В result Выводится сообщение, что на ноль делить нельзя. К сожалению, только код ответа остался 200.

Сейчас есть обходной путь — установить версию без mypyc из исходников pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary flask_jsonrpc flask_jsonrpc — и как я понял из исходников, можно взять исключение наподобие from flask_jsonrpc.exceptions import InvalidParamsError и выбросить уже его raise InvalidParamsError(str(exc), code=-32602, status_code=400) — получаемый ответ довольно близок к тому, что вы хотите (но при включенном debug добавляется ещё stack, отключите debug чтобы убрать его)

Правда, разработчики зачем-то сделали ещё засирание логов сервера этими ошибками и не предоставили официального способа это отключить... В общем фигня какая-то, а не библиотека

Ну и в целом, раз нормальную документацию не завезли, посмотреть имеющиеся типы исключений можно в исходниках вот тут https://github.com/cenobites/flask-jsonrpc/blob/v3.0.1/src/flask_jsonrpc/exceptions.py#L47 (вместо InvalidParamsError можно взять более подходящее, и кстати code указывать не обязательно, я забыл стереть из своего комментария)

@andreymal Я использовал 3 на мой взгляд возможных исключения (InvalidParamsError, InvalidParamsError, ServerError), к примеру так except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
raise InvalidParamsError(code=-32602, message=str(exc), status_code=400), но к сожалению результат код 500

@andreymal Андрей,  если бы не твоя помощь, оставил всё как есть и переключился на другое. Так что, большое тебе спасибо.

Разработчики удалили бинарные сборки с PyPI, так что теперь после переустановки flask_jsonrpc вышеописанное выбрасывание ошибок должно работать без плясок с бубном

@andreymal Спасибо.

@jsonrpc.method("calc.truediv")
def truediv(a: float, b: float) -> float | str:
    try:
        result = operator.truediv(a, b)
        return result
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "На ноль делить нельзя", 400

Можно ещё так:
except ZeroDivisionError:
    return {"error": "На ноль делить нельзя"}, 400

